# Sitecore how to check does sitecore content tree item available for extranet/anomouse user

Tags: web, sitecore, sitecore6

Hello is is possible to define grammatically does extranet/anonym user has access to content tree item ?
I need it like additional case in my IHttpModule.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AuthorizationManager` class to get any access right information like this:

```
Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationManager.IsAllowed(
        item, 
        Sitecore.Security.AccessControl.AccessRight.ItemRead, 
        User.FromName("domain\\name", AccountType.User)
);
```